# Merging PDF easily with pdftools

Tags: r, pdf, merge

I'm doing several webscraping which returns daily pdf's in some directory (path) I need to find someway to get all files in as easy way. For now I'm listing all the files one by one. Is there an easy way to do it?

```
data_download
pdf_01 <- paste("path\\", data_download, " - MK - Debêntures novas.pdf", sep="")
pdf_02 <- paste("path\\", data_download, " - MK - Fundos novos.pdf", sep="")
pdf_03 <- paste("path\\", data_download, " - News - Instruções CVM.pdf", sep="")
pdf_04 <- paste("path\\", data_download, " - News - Notícias CVM.pdf", sep="")

pdf_merged <- paste("path\\", data_download, " - Novidades de hoje.pdf", sep="")

pdf_combine(c(pdf_01,pdf_02,pdf_03,pdf_04) ,output  = pdf_merged)
```

Comment: `list.files()` may be the answer if you want to merge all the PDFs, otherwise you'll need to explain how to select the files that you want merging

Comment: Tks @Miff. How can I put this list inside an c() so it can be merged? tks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `list.files()` gets you most of the way to what you want, if you want all the files in your path folder  that contain "pdf" in the name to be merged, you could do something like:

```
pdf_combine(list.files(path, pattern="pdf", full.names=TRUE), output  = pdf_merged)
```